# Java beginners coding error - method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I have a little code that errors and i'm sure that it is a simple fix with the code. The idea is that you type the name of an animal in, and if it contains "dog" then the noise the animal makes is output to the screen:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What animal is it?");
    String animal = sc.nextLine();

    if (animal.contains("dog")) {
        System.out.println("WOOF!");
    }
  }  
}
```

The message received when I try to run the code displays:

```
Main.java:17: error: method contains in class String cannot be applied to given types;
    if(animal.contains()) {
             ^
  required: CharSequence
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

exit status 1
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: The error message is not from the code you're showing us.

Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you _save_ the actual code you posted before building/compiling the  code?  Also, note that you appear to have an extra parenthesis at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler isn't receiving the same code as you are showing us. In your code, the `if` statement's `String.contains()` has a `CharSequence`  argument, but the code the compiler is receiving has the `String.contains()` without an argument. You've just made the simple error of forgetting to save, or of giving the compiler the wrong file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the String == dog

```
if(animal.equals("dog")){
    System.out.println("WOOF!");
}
```

Comment: This might be the answer in C++ but not Java :-(

Comment: Don't compare Strings with == .

Comment: `== true` is entirely superfluous.

Comment: just use the equals() method.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a school boy error. I thought the error was relating to the 1st if statement.....it wasn't, it was referring to the last one:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What animal is it?");

    String animal = sc.nextLine();

    if(animal.contains("dog")){
        System.out.println("WOOF!");
    }

    if(animal.contains("cat")) {

    }

    if(animal.contains()) {

    }



  }
}
```

The compliler didn't hightlight the line responsible so I thought it was the first "if" line.

So when I add the following the code works:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What animal is it?");

    String animal = sc.nextLine();

    if(animal.contains("dog")){
        System.out.println("WOOF!");
    }

    if(animal.contains("cat")) {

    }

    if(animal.contains("numpty")) {

    }



  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you see now the reason to always provide a [mcve]?